# HttpClient: Can´t access to response headers

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient

In a project, we used both Http & HttpClient to fetch the header params. Http returns the header params, but HttpClient doesn't.

```
constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
getContent() {
        const url = '';
        return this.http.post(url, data)
            .map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                console.log('http content', res);
            });


        return this.httpClient.post(url, data, { observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                console.log('httpClient content',res);
            });
}
```

When checked in console, http returns the response with headers but httpClient returns an empty array in headers.

When checked in networks tab of browser inspector, it displays all the header parameters.

The server accepts the following CORS options:

```
  origin: '*',
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: 'Origin,X-Requested-With,x-access-token,Content-Type,Authorization,Accept,jwt',
  exposedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization,jwt'
```

Please help me figure out how to fetch the headers using httpClient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should not use both (http & httpClient) in the same project, try to remove http and check.

Comment: Try to remove type of res

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right track with the HttpClient. You should use the `get()` method on your headers.

```
this.httpClient.post(url, data, {observe: 'response'})
    .map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        let myHeader = res.headers.get('my-header');
        return res;
    });
```

Where `my-header` is the header response you are trying to fetch.

Comment: This helped me after scratching my head for 2 hours. Thank You