# Httpclient response null when calling Java Servlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some difficulty figuring out why im getting a null response in angular when i try to do a post to a httpservlet (java) in a WAS environment.

What im trying to do is call an api to login. I would like to receive the response headers, but im getting a null response, making it impossible to do anything with the response.

I tried to send my parameters as form data with the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 and as query parameters with no content-type defined.

In both situations im able to login and im getting a 200 response with header information in my browser.

this is my call

```js
    return this.http.post(this.contextRoot.getHost() + 'osa-kantoor-ws/api/auth/login?' + param1 + "&" + param2,null, this.httpOptions).map((res : Response) => {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(username));
      return res;
    });
```

My header info now is

```js
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Accept':  'application/text'}),
    params: {}
  };
```

the localstorage item is set, but the response information is null.

this is my subscribe

```js
 login() {
    this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value.userName,this.loginForm.value.password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.loginfail = true;
        });
  }
```

When im checking the browser info on my response header i get the following info

[image]

can anyone tell me what im missing?

below is the original method

```js
 login(username: string, password: string) {
    let param1: string = encodeURIComponent('userName') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(username);
    let param2: string = encodeURIComponent('password') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(password);
    let formParams: string = param1 + '&' + param2;
    return this.http.post(this.contextRoot.getHost() + 'osa-kantoor-ws/api/auth/login', formParams, this.httpOptions).map(response=> {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(username));
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does the server send back as response body? What do you expect to happen? And why do you send the credentials as part of the URL, instead of sending them in the body? You really don't want the passwords to appear in the server logs.

Comment: I used this as another approach to see if anything will change if i send the params as url params, the original approach is to send it as form data, which of course is in the body. The response body is empty, because the servlet does not give any other information then a status 200 with header information (like the cookie)

Comment: I guess you want to observe the response ? https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394326/7741865

Comment: If the response body is empty, what are you surprised to get null as the response body? What else do you expect and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thank you AJT_82,

adding  observe: 'response' to the config is the solution.

response is now what i expect. the default response is   observe: 'body' apparently.

My HTTP config is now

```js
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8','Accept':  'application/xml'}),
    observe: 'response'
  };
```

and my response is now

[image]